# Armadillo altering entire columns instead of singular elements when attempting to copy from another matrix class

Tags: c++, armadillo

I am trying to copy a matrix from an old matrix class to an armadillo matrix. Unfortunately when attempting to do this with a for loop the armadillo matrix will copy the value from the old matrix to the ENTIRE column when the lowest-most element is non-zero (I am using sparse matrices). I have attached the code that is being used below. This is very simplified because I need to figure out why it is doing this first. According to the documentation this should work.

```cpp
main()
{
     OldMatrixClass MatrixA(size, size);
     FillMatrix(MatrixA, size);
     for (auto i = 0; i < size; i++) 
     {
         for (auto j = 0; j < size; j++) 
         {
             file << MatrixA[i][j] << "\t";
         }
         file << "\n";
     }
     arma::Mat<double> ArmaA(size, size);
     ArmaA.zeros();
     CopyMatrix(MatrixA, ArmaA, size);
     for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) 
     {
         for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) 
         {
             file << ArmaA[i,j] << "\t";
         }
         file << "\n";
     }
}

void FillMatrix(OldMatrixClass &A, int size)
{

     double num = 0.15;

     for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
     {
         for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
         {
             if (rand() % 101 < 26)
             {
                 A[i][j] = num;
             }
             else
             {
                 A[i][j] = 0;
             }
         }
     }
}

void CopyMatrix(OldMatrixClass A, arma::Mat<double> &B, int size)
{
     for (int k = 0; k < size; k++)
     {
         for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
         {

             B[j, k] = A[j][k];
         }
     }
}
```

This is the output when I run this code... As you can see only the entire columns are altered if the last element in MatrixA column is non-zero.
[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4zZhn.png)

Is there something I'm doing wrong? Is my syntax messed up somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

See [the documentation](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html):

> Caveat: accessing elements via [i,j] and [i,j,k] does not work correctly in C++; instead use (i,j) and (i,j,k)

Comment: Both [i,j] and (i,j) do not work. Both yield same result.